# Cronbach's alpha for one scale but different types of items

Tags: survey, reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I developed a questionnaire on art expertise. There are 3 rather subjective questions("I know much about art","I know more than the average citizen","I am able to identify an artwork by a popular artist") evaluated on 7-point likert scales (not at all - absolutely). Furthermore, there are multiple rather objective questions like ("How many hours do you deal with art publications per month") etc. with differing numbers of answering options, scaled ordinally and coded with some number from 1-n.

Now I want to use Cronbach's alpha to assess the internal consistency of my questionnaire. I used it on the subjective scales and got a alpha=0.93 which is not too bad. Now I wonder: can I use it on the objective scales as well, although they have different numbers of options, or can I even use it on the whole questionnaire? Answer option alternatives range from 2-6.

Comment: A remark: does it probably make sense to z-transform the different item distributions in order to make them compareable?

Comment: Just a remark: I came across this paper (Sheng, Y., & Sheng, Z. (2012). Is coefficient alpha robust to non-normal data? Frontiers in psychology, 3(February), 34. doi:10.3389/fpsyg.2012.00034). It supports my doubts that Cronbach's alpha might not work correctly with non-normal data, because it is based on variances that in turn assume normality. I evaluated my questionnaire and only combined responses from normally distributed responses.